# How to use Apache Wicket for developing Youtube/Facebook kind of "load more results" pages"?

Tags: ajax, wicket

We are using Wicket intensively at our company.
I need to develop an application that contains a page that should show a large number of (search) results. Pagination is not an option for that page, we need an endless scrolling or load more results functionality.

Can this be done in an easy, maintainable way using Apache Wicket?
If so, how would I go about?

Can I also stay with Wicket if my web application must also be mobile responsive, or is Wicket not the best option for this?

Given the above requirements is Wicket a no go and should I go for other web application frameworks (like AngularJS or ReactJS)?

Comment: Wickets presentation can very well include responsive and mobile friendly if you configure it to be. You can of course include the required styles and scripts in every page you build.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this can be done. Wicket is perfectly suited for this task.

You should look up some components that implement it, rather than write it again :)

For example: [Infinite scroll](https://github.com/l0rdn1kk0n/wicket-bootstrap/blob/master/bootstrap-samples/src/main/java/de/agilecoders/wicket/samples/panels/pagination/InfinitePaginationPanel.java)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Quickview](https://github.com/vineetsemwal/quickview):

It can be used very similarly to a ListView with the following usage:

```
new QuickView<T>(id, dataProvider, new ItemsNavigationStrategy(), itemsPerRequest) { 
    @Override
    protected void populate(Item<T> item) {
        //populate item here, like a listview
    }
}
```

It behaves just like a ListView but when reaching the bottom of the view, more entries are loaded according to the dataProvider until all entries are displayed.